# Cannot write to boot disk, asks authentication

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, snow-leopard, mac-pro

### Problem

Suddenly, after rebooting a Snow Leopard Mac Pro (2009), I cannot copy to the main disk, or even move one of its files, without having Mac OS X asking for authentication.

Once I type the password in the dialog box, the copy is made, but this is not acceptable nor usable in the long term. I even think most apps won't like it...

[image]

I'm talking about copying a file from the Desktop to somewhere else on the same disk, the one the system has booted on...!

### History

2 x Mac Pro 2009, one has Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard working properly, the second one has nothing.

I used Copy Carbon Cloner to make a clone of the first Mac on another disk then installed the copy in the second machine.

It worked for some time! Then, on this second Mac, I added another disk in bay 3 and things started to go south. I think the disk in bay 3 was faulty.

So I stopped the machine, removed the faulty disk from bay 3, and rebooted. And here the authentication problem on the main disk appeared.

### What has been done

I've booted from another system partition on another disk then used Disk Utility to repair the disk and to repair permissions. No errors were detected.

I researched other answers to similar questions but they are all about using an NTFS disk, and this is not my case at all, I'm talking about a standard HFS+ Mac OS X disk that suddenly is in this "read only" mode.

### Other info

If I add another disk with Yosemite installed, I can boot on it and I can copy/move/write anything on the Yosemite disk *and* on the Snow Leopard one.

But I absolutely need to have the Snow Leopard one also working (because of obsolete apps we still need) and rebooting again on it, the problem is still here.

### TL;DR

In a 2009 Mac Pro, a cloned Snow Leopard disk asks for authentication for any file operation.

In the same Mac Pro, a Yosemite disk works properly and does not suffer from this issue, I can move files on the Yosemite disk and on the Snow Leopard disk.

Back on the Snow leopard one: the authentication problem is still here, for all disks in the machine.

### Result of operations asked in comments

Asked by seaturtle:

```
cd ~; ls -ale | grep -e '^ [0-9]*:' -B 1 | grep -v '^--$'

drwxr-xr-x@ 15 lollipopmusic  staff    510 17 oct 16:40 .
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------@ 30 lollipopmusic  staff   1020 17 oct 16:43 Desktop
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------@ 35 lollipopmusic  staff   1190 17 oct 16:10 Documents
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------@  5 lollipopmusic  staff    170  1 jui  2010 Downloads
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------@ 32 lollipopmusic  staff   1088 24 avr  2012 Library
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------@  3 lollipopmusic  staff    102 27 mai  2010 Movies
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------@  6 lollipopmusic  staff    204 22 fév  2011 Music
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------@  4 lollipopmusic  staff    136 27 mai  2010 Pictures
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwxr-xr-x@  5 lollipopmusic  staff    170 27 mai  2010 Public
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwxr-xr-x@  5 lollipopmusic  staff    170 27 mai  2010 Sites
 0: group:everyone deny delete
```

and:

```
total 32
drwxr-xr-x@ 15 lollipopmusic  staff    510 17 oct 16:40 .
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwxr-xr-x@  6 root           admin    204  1 fév  2011 ..
-rw-------@  1 lollipopmusic  staff      5 27 mai  2010 .CFUserTextEncoding
-rw-r--r--@  1 lollipopmusic  staff  15364 17 oct 16:11 .DS_Store
drwx------   4 lollipopmusic  staff    136 17 oct 16:43 .Trash
drwx------@ 30 lollipopmusic  staff   1020 17 oct 16:43 Desktop
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------@ 35 lollipopmusic  staff   1190 17 oct 16:10 Documents
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------@  5 lollipopmusic  staff    170  1 jui  2010 Downloads
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------@ 32 lollipopmusic  staff   1088 24 avr  2012 Library
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------@  3 lollipopmusic  staff    102 27 mai  2010 Movies
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------@  6 lollipopmusic  staff    204 22 fév  2011 Music
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------@  4 lollipopmusic  staff    136 27 mai  2010 Pictures
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwxr-xr-x@  5 lollipopmusic  staff    170 27 mai  2010 Public
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwxr-xr-x   3 lollipopmusic  staff    102 17 oct 16:11 RECUPS
drwxr-xr-x@  5 lollipopmusic  staff    170 27 mai  2010 Sites
 0: group:everyone deny delete
```

Asked by klanomath:

```
sudo ls -lae /

drwxrwxr-x@ 30 root           wheel         1088 17 oct 16:43 .
drwxrwxr-x@ 30 root           wheel         1088 17 oct 16:43 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 lollipopmusic  admin        12292 17 oct 17:04 .DS_Store
drwx------@  5 _unknown       _unknown       170 12 oct 15:07 .Spotlight-V100
d-wx-wx-wt@  2 _unknown       _unknown        68 17 oct 17:04 .Trashes
-rw-r--r--@  1 _unknown       _unknown         0 12 oct 15:07 .com.apple.timemachine.donotpresent
----------@  1 root           admin            0  5 oct  2009 .file
drwx------@  8 _unknown       _unknown       272 17 oct 17:04 .fseventsd
-rw-------@  1 root           wheel        65536 12 oct 16:20 .hotfiles.btree
drwxr-xr-x@  2 root           wheel           68 18 mai  2009 .vol
drwxrwxr-x@ 49 root           admin         1666  2 jan  2012 Applications
 0: group:everyone deny delete
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root           admin           60 13 sep  2016 Guides de l’utilisateur et informations -> /Library/Documentation/User Guides and Information.localized
drwxrwxr-t@ 55 root           admin         1870  1 jui  2010 Library
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwxr-xr-x@  2 root           wheel           68  5 oct  2009 Network
drwxr-xr-x@  5 root           wheel          170  7 fév  2011 System
drwxr-xr-x@  6 root           admin          204  1 fév  2011 Users
drwxrwxrwt@  5 root           admin          170 17 oct 17:35 Volumes
 0: group:everyone deny add_file,add_subdirectory,directory_inherit,only_inherit
drwxr-xr-x@ 39 root           wheel         1326  4 nov  2009 bin
dr-xr-xr-x   3 root           wheel         4259 17 oct 17:05 dev
lrwxr-xr-x@  1 root           wheel           11 13 sep  2016 etc -> private/etc
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root           wheel            1 17 oct 17:05 home
-rw-r--r--@  1 root           wheel     18676624  4 nov  2009 mach_kernel
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root           wheel            1 17 oct 17:05 net
drwxr-xr-x@  6 root           wheel          204  4 nov  2009 private
drwxr-xr-x@ 64 root           wheel         2176  4 nov  2009 sbin
lrwxr-xr-x@  1 root           wheel           11 13 sep  2016 tmp -> private/tmp
drwxr-xr-x@ 11 root           wheel          374 27 mai  2010 usr
lrwxr-xr-x@  1 root           wheel           11 13 sep  2016 var -> private/var
```

and:

```
sudo ls -lae ~/  

drwx------@  30 lollipopmusic  staff      1020 17 oct 16:43 .  
 0: group:everyone deny delete  
drwxr-xr-x@  15 lollipopmusic  staff       510 17 oct 16:40 ..  
 0: group:everyone deny delete
```

Comment: Try `cd ~; ls -ale | grep -e '^ [0-9]*:' -B 1 | grep -v '^--$'` in the Terminal -- does it give any output? Mine has `0: group:everyone deny delete` on several folders, but I'm wondering if there's one preventing you from modifying things at all (like `deny write` or something).

Comment: What this does: `cd ~` moves to your home folder, `ls -ale` lists the files, and the `grep`s filter for ACLs and remove `--` separating lines, respectively.

Comment: I just realized I didn't explain ACLs -- it means "Access Control List", and specifies who can do what with a file, independently of permissions. This lets you do things like give specific users access but deny other people.

Comment: @seaturtle Thanks. Running this command lists the main folders (Desktop, Documents, Downloads, etc). It also gives me "0: group:everyone deny delete" on *all* folders! Is this the issue?

Comment: Please add - booted to the misbehaving SL - the output of `sudo ls -lae /` and `sudo ls -lae ~/` entered in Terminal to your question.

Comment: @Moritz: _All_ folders? Probably. I would run `chmod -RN <folder>` on every folder that has it that _isn't_ a main folder, as in Harcker's answer. If you do `cd ~/Desktop` instead of `cd ~` in that command, does it give any more ACLs?

Comment: @klanomath I've added the commands results in the question.

Comment: Hm. There aren't any ACLs out of place directly in your home directory -- how about your Desktop?

Comment: @seaturtle I just added it to the question.

Comment: Whoops, I forgot -- that first command _should_ list the `everyone deny delete` on all folders, because it filters out the ones that don't have any ACLs. (:

Comment: @seaturtle Ok. I've since discovered that I can actually write/copy on this disk, but not on root. It only works in Desktop, Documents, etc. I'm a bit lost: will the system and apps work properly if I leave it like that? Did I just panic for nothing? :D

Comment: On root ... like at the actual root, `/`? Or at the root of your home folder?

Comment: @seaturtle At root `/`

Comment: @seaturtle Thanks a lot for your help. I've followed Harcker's solution and it seems to have fixed this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this instead:

Open Finder, find your drive, typically named "Macintosh HD"(but in your case "MAC106"), select it, press `Command (⌘) + I` on your keyboard, in the window that opens, scroll to the bottom, if the text next to your username is "read and write", this isn't the solution, but if the text is "Read Only", do this:

Click the padlock, type your credentials, click the "Read Only" tag next to your username, click on "Read & Write", click on the padlock, and done.

Comment: There's `system: read/write, wheel: read/write, everyone: read`.

Comment: Okay, unlock the padlock, click on the + button, click on your username, click on the blue add button, and then set your account to “Read & Write” as mentioned in my answer above.

Comment: Looks like it solved the issue! Thanks a lot!!! :)

Comment: You just have to be aware that this will give any application you run access to the root of the disk...

Comment: Good to know. Not an issue for this machine (it's not connected to Internet and nobody installs anything on it but me). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Before you do this, always make sure you have a recent backup!

Is your problem only at the root level, or in every folder?

If it’s in every folder try this solution, it’ll remake all file permissions: launch the Terminal from /Applications/Utilities/, type this command: `sudo chmod -RN ~/Desktop`, press enter, type your password, and press enter again. Wait for the command to finish (it can take some time).

If this makes you able use your desktop as Read/Write, you can try doing this `sudo chmod -RN /`, it’ll do the same but for the whole disk instead.

Before you do this, always make sure you have a recent backup!

Comment: Nice, didn't know about `chmod -N`. I'd just like to point out, though, that OS X ships with ACLs on Desktop, Documents, etc. as well as the home folder, and this will probably remove them. The `-N` doesn't remake all permissions, it removes ACLs (which can still be helpful, it's what I was getting at in my comment).

Comment: `Is your problem only at the root level, or in every folder?` Mm, I didn't notice that before: only at root, it seems. I just created a folder on the Desktop and in Documents successfully.

Comment: okay, if so, don't follow my answer,